# How to remove previous li when making selections?

Tags: jquery

I have no problems generating a new li list using the code below. The problem is I can't generate a li list after generating a new list. I think if making a selection the previous list is removed it would work but need help is accomplishing this.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() 
{

    $("#optionA, #optionB").change(function()
    {
            var fileName = $('#optionB').val() + '_' +  $('#optionA.val() + '.txt';

        $.getJSON(fileName, function(data) 
                {
                $.each(data, function(i,el) 
                {
                              $("ul").append("<li>" + el.name + "</li>");
                });
        });
    });
});
```

Updated code

```
<select id="optionA">
    <option value="a"> A </option>
    <option value="b"> B </option>
    <option value="c"> C </option>
    <option value="d"> D </option>
</select>
<select id="optionB">
    <option value="e"> E </option>
    <option value="f"> F </option>
    <option value="g"> G </option>
    <option value="h"> H </option>
</select>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() 
    {

        $("#optionA, #optionB").change(function()
        {
                var fileName = $('#optionB').val() + '_' +  $('#optionA').val() + '.txt';

            $.getJSON(fileName, function(data) 
                    {
                    alert(fileName);
                    $.each(data, function(i,el) 
                    {
                                  $("ul").append("<li>" + el.name + "</li>");
                    });
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: what is this #optionA, and #optionB . please provide your html

Comment: `$('#optionA.val()` it seems you've lost something, i think it should be: `$('#optionA').val()`

Comment: for example ur el is an anchor <a> in first iteration , el changes to a <div> in next iteration. do u want to remove <a> and append <div>?

Comment: Update to the code but the problem is still the same                                                                   <script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function() 
 {

  $("#optionA, #optionB").change(function()
  {
       var fileName = $('#optionB').val() + '_' +  $('#optionA').val() + '.txt';
   
   $.getJSON(fileName, function(data) 
                 {
     alert(fileName);
     $.each(data, function(i,el) 
     {
                                  $("ul").append("<li>" + el.name + "</li>");
     });
   });
  });
 });
</script>

Comment: @BWR: You can edit your question instead of posting code as a comment.

Comment: optionA and optionB comes from:                                                                  <select id="optionA">
 <option value="a"> A </option>
 <option value="b"> B </option>
 <option value="c"> C </option>
 <option value="d"> D </option>
</select>
<select id="optionB">
 <option value="e"> E </option>
 <option value="f"> F </option>
 <option value="g"> G </option>
 <option value="h"> H </option>
</select>

Answer (score 0):

to all to `ul`  i can't see a `ul`  in your code

try to add this to your code

```
<div id="ulist"><ul></ul></div>
```